# Inverting output of gate driver for MOSFET

Tags: transistors, pwm, mosfet-driver

I am using this circuit to control the speed of a small motor (12VDC, 0.3A).
The arduino PWM output saturates a 2N2222 NPN transistor which saturates the mosfet gate.

My issue: when PWM is high (5V), the output is low at the mosfet (0V = motor stopped). So when my controller starts up, the motor is running until the code applies the max value to the PWM output to shutdown the motor.

What I want to achieve: **PWM high (5V) results in output high.** instead of "PWM high (5V) results in output low".

I could solve it using an opamp to invert the signal but there must be a simpler way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when my controller starts up, the motor is running until the code applies the max value to the PWM output to shutdown the motor.

You can use a pull-up resistor with your existing circuit to ensure the load stays off until your code reaches the point of enabling its output pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff6gxI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I already do it in software, the problem is the small time upon controller startup.
I can only use DIP package... it's on stripboard.

Comment: @Vinlar, you could include a pull-up on the 2N2222 base to keep the motor off until your code gets to the point of enabling the output pin.

Comment: do you mean a 1K pullup to the arduino 5V? in that case if PWM is 0V, I would have a voltage divider in place (2.5V?)

Comment: thanks, I will give a try tonight!! I suppose R2 is the optimal value to saturate the 2N2222 with 5V (1K is a little high), but how do you obtain the 22kOhm for R1?

Comment: @Vinlar, I changed my suggestion to avoid back-flowing current into the UC's output pin when the voltage is high. You want R1 as high as possible but still saturating Q1 when the UC output is disabled. Not knowing if you have a 3.3 V or 5 V micro, I have made guesses at the values --- you'll want to double check how they work. Using a logic-level MOSFET instead of a BJT for Q1 might simplify things.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I can't find logic-level MOSFET where I live unfortunately (I looked at this option initially), but the IRF630 is cheap and widely available. My controller (arduino) works with 5V logic.

Comment: @Vinlar, in that case you might want to increase R1 to 10k. You might also want increase R2 somewhat depending on the current drive capability of the micro.

Comment: @Vinlar Does 5 V Vcc come up at a different time than the 12 V supply?

Comment: @jonk I turn on everything on the same time with a single switch (the Vcc and the 12V supply for the motor)

Comment: @Vinlar Thanks and appreciated. Have you scoped the supply rails? How certain do you need to be that the motor doesn't turn on until software can get control of the I/O?

Comment: @jonk I just need avoid that the motor starts up before the software gets the control. As you may now, Arduino analogwrite function is 0 at startup (which results in +12V at my motor), once code boots up, analogwrite is 255 and motor turns off. It is turned on during a couple of seconds at max.

Comment: @Vinlar I'm thinking at a somewhat lower level (and faster) than an analogwrite function. Long before any library code has any chance to do anything, in fact. So, while analogwrite may be 0 at startup, there is a period of time prior to any of that where no software has done anything to configure any I/O and the power-up state is what's specified by the MCU manufacturer's datasheet and has nothing whatever to do with Arduino library functions. No problem, though. I was curious and I think you've explained the level where your thinking is at. Given that, I don't have much to add. Thanks!

Comment: Nice it works. I used r2=330 and r1=10k. Thank you.